# Stop IIS logging

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

Is it possible in IIS to stop logging "GET/POST" events with normal completion (200) and only log errors? If it is possible, how would I do it? I have ISS version 8.5.9600.16384
I have also attached a snip of the file log.

[image]

Thanks,
Val

Comment: Maybe this article can help you: [Advanced Logging for IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging#using)

Comment: So, you want to discard all statistics about your site? No IPs, no browser statistics, no clickstream, nothing? And when a bot, scraper or other kind of malware starts hitting your site to the point of collapse, you want no evidence?

Comment: You probably want to ask how to use a different logging method, or use different logging limits. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve and why do you think that the solution is to disable logging?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on Windows Server or as standalone? There is no advanced logging modules in IIS 8.5. For this type of logging you must set a custom rule in the 'Failed Request Tracing' module. First you need to install the tracing module to IIS. Here are instructions for Windows Server:
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/tracing

Once you have this completed, your custom rule can log 500/200/XXX requests with your custom settings.